# Where can I find a good tutorial to start programming using Cocos2D-x?

Tags: android, linux, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-x

I have some problems to start programming using cocos2D on linux + android.

I use the stable release 0.12.0 (2012-03-05)

- I compile create-linux-eclipse-project.sh correctly
- It create a TestCocos2D project on the same path
- I import the android project to Eclipse
- I run project and i get the hello world.

But i don't know where start programming the scenes, the director, and how to use it.

I have tried [This tutorial](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/) but is too old.
I can't use the [official](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_2_-_How_to_Add_a_sprite) tutorial because i don' t know where use the code.

Some advice/tutorials to start please?

SOLUTION:

If you are here looking for tutorials, try [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364)

Comment: I'm always tempted to answer "Where can I find a tutorial for xxx?" with: "On the Internet of course!". :)

Comment: Yes, but i don't find one enoght good on Android, i will work in one explaining all the steps :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*cocos2d - android* is not updated anymnore. If you are already using Cocos2d-x = crossplatform, you must know that, differently from iOS, in Android you program directly on cpp. The eclipse project uses makefiles to compile the code in cpp, but that code is not with $YOURCOCOS2DPROJECT>android path, it's inside the Classes that Android.mk, compiles the code when uses the eclipse project, and you must put your director, scene and layers over there.

Answer (score 4):

I won't prefer Cocos2d for Android because Cocos2d has not released a stable version of it for a long time. I don't think they are adding more support to it in future. 
Instead go for Cocos2d-x.
For more info go to
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

You can create ios+Android game at one go. :)

Comment: I use that web to take stable version, and i create the project following the wiki tutorials. But i don 't know how cocos2d's project work in android, because i can not to discover where i have to put the director, calls to gamelayer... etc. In Cocos2DActivity? in the java created?? How using the libs?¿

Comment: I also started to work on Cocos2d for Android but its a bit hazy and there are so many things 1 needs to understand to start the real coding stuff. Moreover its not updated for a long time. I would suggest to quit Cocos2d for Android. Go for Cocos2d-x.

Comment: I'm already using it, i gonna look for the Classes code to start